# Elasticsearch as Image Server vs Apache

Tags: html, elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch to query stock quotes. My browser calls the elastic cluster which returns a list of urls inside of `<img>` tags. The browser then calls the images (stock charts of associated quote). These images are on a separate Apache 2 http server. Both servers are identical Centos Quad core 2.0Ghz, 16GB RAM, 1Tb HD.

From reading [previous SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234258/save-image-in-elasticsearch-with-ruby) it seems one can store base64 images in Elasticsearch.

Has anyone created a production image server in elasticsearch and perhaps compared benchmarks to a static web server? In my case the images are 80 to 150 kb.

My specific question is (1) Would it be faster to have the image in my document map as binary and elastic reply back base64 images as opposed to `<img>` tags which then require another call to Apache? (2) Is elasticsearch as an image server comparable to static nginx or apache image server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elasticsearch is a **search engine** (among other things) which excels at providing fast searches for your data. It is **not a content server**.

The only reason I would store images in ES would be if I needed to [search for similar images](https://github.com/kzwang/elasticsearch-image). In your case, you seem to be willing to use Elasticsearch as a content server to retrieve your images, which would be better stored on a content delivery network (CDN) as you're doing now with your second Apache server.

Pragmatically, though, it's probably ok to store the base64 of your images in ES if you have a few stock quote documents, i.e. not millions.

The best thing to do is always to try it out and see how your cluster handles it. Maybe for your specific use case it's perfectly ok. It's just that you'll be putting an extra load on ES, which it isn't meant to handle in the first place.

For instance, if you return ten results, your response will grow from a few KB to at least 1 MB and your users will need to wait for that transfer to be done in order to see some results, whereas if you stored your images elsewhere, you could at least show the results very quickly to the user and let the browser handle the image retrieval asynchronously without having to care about it.

Comment: Good to know, thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible to store binary data in a search index you should avoid doing so for large binaries.

Storing binaries as in-memory fielddata (FieldCache) can make your system quickly running out of heap space whereas storing them as disk-based fielddata (DocValues) - making ElasticSearch behave more like a typical "column store" - will load the images of **all** documents to the file system cache. (DocValues are documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html#doc-values)).

Therefore, serving and caching images from nginx or Apache still seems the better choice.