# Can we save image in ElasticSearch such that we can retrieve image with url like <img src="xyx.com/image/234">

Tags: html, elasticsearch

I want to access image stored in ElasticSearch directly in src attribute of html img element. Is there any way to achieve this exactly or ....?

Actually i want images hit elasticsearch only if browser does not have image. 
If there is an alternate way to do easily work around images. Please suggest.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781654/elasticsearch-as-image-server-vs-apache/34781951#34781951

Comment: @Val Above link is helpful. Could you tell me, how do you copy link of any answer in stackoverflow. Thank you.

Comment: At the bottom of the answer there's a "share" link, click on it and then you can copy/paste the link.